# Java regex on doubles

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to check for a double that has a maximum of 13 digits before the decimal point and the decimal point and numbers following it are optional. So the user could write a whole number or a number with decimals.

To start with I had this:

```
if (check.matches("[0-9](.[0-9]*)?"))
```

I've been through several pages on Google and haven't had any luck getting it working despite various efforts. My thought was to do it like this but it doesn't work:

```
[0-9]{1,13}(.[0-9]*)?
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why don't you just parse the `double` and check for `value < 10000000000000`?

Comment: \\. OR [.] Both works, but don't just write '.'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't forget to escape the dot.

```
if (check.matches("[0-9]{1,13}(\\.[0-9]*)?"))
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. I tried something similar but I was a bit naive to try use a regex checker online which can't accept "\\". Should have just tried it in the program.

Answer (score 5):

First of all you need to escape the dot(in java this would be `[0-9]{1,13}(\\.[0-9]*)?`). Second of all don't forget there is also another popular representation of doubles - scientific. So this `1.5e+4` is again a valid double number. And lastly don't forget a double number may be negative, or may not have a whole part at all. E.g. `-1.3` and `.56` are valid doubles.

Comment: It's for an accounting system exercise where we can't have negative numbers.

Comment: Any solution that handles all these cases ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the dot and you need at least on digit after the dot

```
[0-9]{1,13}(\\.[0-9]+)?
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33iga)

Answer (score 1):

John's answer is close.  But a '-' needs to be added, in case it's negative, if you accept negative values.  So, it would be modified to `-?[0-9]{1,13}(\.[0-9]*)?`

Answer (score 1):

if you need to validate decimal with commas and negatives:

```
Object testObject = "-1.5";
boolean isDecimal = Pattern.matches("^[\\+\\-]{0,1}[0-9]+[\\.\\,]{1}[0-9]+$", (CharSequence) testObject);
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use \d+(\.\d*)?  as below in kotlin language-

```
    val rawString = "Hi..  2345.97 ..Bye"
    val DOUBLE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d*)?")
    val matcher = DOUBLE_PATTERN.matcher(rawString)
    var filterNumber = 0.0
    if (matcher.find())
        filterNumber = matcher.group() // extracted number- 2345.97
```