# Jmeter: Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Double.parseDouble

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jsonpath

Hey I'm doing some beanshell scripting for API testing in jmeter. I've written quite a few jmeter scripts with beanshell and it works fine when using `Integer.parseInt()` method invocation, but I have a value with decimal places where my SQL returns a value of 20.00000 and my Json path extractor gets 20.0 so my test fails when comparing it. Because of this problem I decided to compare this values as double variables instead of Strings but I'm getting the error bellow when using Double.parseDouble on BeanShell.

> 2016/08/17 12:48:45 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `print("Width Assertion...");  int Total_Printers_SQL = Integer.parseInt(vars.get . . . ''` : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Double.parseDouble
>
> 2016/08/17 12:48:45 WARN  - jmeter.assertions.BeanShellAssertion: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `print("Width Assertion...");  int Total_Printers_SQL = Integer.parseInt(vars.get . . . ''` : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Double.parseDouble

Even with the errors displayed the value of the double variable is printed on Jmeter prompt as you can see below.

[image]

If anyone's a beanshell expert and could help me identify the error, that'd be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Try with `Double.parseDouble(vars.get("Printer_Width_SQL_" + i).toString())`... It might need "to be told" it's a string.

Answer (score 2):

If the number you get is not a valid `Double` (`1.2s` for example, or just `null`), you will get such exception. The cure is either checking that the value [is double by RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563106/java-regex-on-doubles), or simply [trying to parse, and catching exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133770/how-to-find-out-if-the-value-contained-in-a-string-is-double-or-not) (note that Beanhell does not pass exceptions properly, so you will have to check for any exception, so it's better to limit it to that one line):

```
double x = 0.0; // default value
String value = vars.get("myVar");
try
{
    x = Double.parseDouble(value);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    log.info("Cannot parse " + value + " as double");
}
```