# Cucumber expression support for double NaN (in Java)

Tags: java, cucumber

```
  Given Java is a language supporting Double.NaN
  Then cucumber's double expression should support 1.234 
  And cucumber's double expression should support NaN <<< FAIL
```

and

```java
  @Given("cucumber's double expression should support {double}")
  public void check(double expected) {}
```

Is there a proper method to make this work with the builtins?

Comment: Upvoted for the snarky Gherkin.

Comment: TL;DR: No. There is not.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to introduce custom parameter like this:

```java
public class StepDef {

    @ParameterType(".*")
    public Double doubleNaNable(String val){
        try{
            return Double.parseDouble(val);
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
            return Double.NaN;
        }
    }

    @Given("Java is a language supporting Double.NaN")
    public void givenStep() {
        System.out.println("Java is a language supporting Double.NaN");
    }
    @Then("cucumber's double expression should support {doubleNaNable}")
    public void thenStep(double value) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }

}
```

More nice way is to add your text representation of NaN to regexp that captures double value from gherkin.

Comment: Indeed. That `.*` loses the nice snippet-generation unless you try to write a much more complete (and less greedy) regex (which _none_ of the examples here do:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563106/java-regex-on-doubles)

Comment: Returning `NaN` on exception is definitely wrong logic. Would take ages to debug that one :)